# dynamic memory allocation with strings and fixed sized

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, c-strings, allocation

I'm trying to allocate memory for strings, but no matter what I do, I always allocate memory for seven characters, even changing the size. can someone help please?

```
#include <stdio_ext.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
    
int main() 
{
    char *s;
    int n;  

    printf("string size? ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    
    __fpurge(stdin); 

    
    s = (char *)malloc((n+1) * sizeof(char));
    if (!s)
    {
        printf("not possible\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    printf("Enter the string: ");
    fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin);

    printf("String: %s\n",s);

    free(s);
}
```

Comment: `fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin);` --> `fgets(s, n + 1, stdin);` , `sizeof(s)` returns the size of a pointer to `char` (usually 8)

Comment: @DavidRanieri What is `strlef`?

Comment: @user58697 typo: `strlen`, but `strlen` was also wrong, the correct param for `fgets` is `n + 1`

Comment: mkulberg, When you request string size, are you accounting for the `'\n'` of `fgets()`?  To read the entire line of "abc\n", the allocation needed is 5.

Comment: Off-Topic: Do not cast the result of `malloc()`. Replace the `printf()` for `"not possible\n"` with `perror("<your error message>")` (that will show the error from `malloc()`)

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof(s)` returns size of pointer which is 8 in your case, you should rewrite this `fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin);` with this `fgets(s, n + 1, stdin);`.